# How to normalize images using mean and std?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, normalization

I am trying to use **numpy** to normalize a set of MRI images, but it seems to be not working. The simplified code is:

```py
img = nib.load(img_path).get_data() #img is a numpy array
print("pre\n============================")
plt.imshow(img[:,:,100])
plt.ioff()
plt.show()

img = (img - 47.08389527329749)/125.64995558389833

print("post\n============================")
plt.imshow(img[:,:,100])
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

To calculate the **mean** and **std** values with numpy:

```py
mean = np.mean(image_list) # 47.08389527329749
std = np.std(image_list) # 125.64995558389833
```

But the result images are similar:

> pre:

[image]

> post:

[image]

Which part am I doing wrong here?

Comment: why do you think anything is wrong? add colorbars to the plots. I bet the range of values in each image is different

Comment: Thanks, I understand now that the normalization is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should print the numerical values of your matrix and not plot the images. I think the process went fine.
**Normalization has the purpose to center the values in a given interval**, here the values of a standard normal distribution, and set the same range if you use several attributes. It is not supposed to remove the relative differences between values of a given attribute, here the pixels intensities.